# Is it possible to export a JPEG at a lower resolution without flattening layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've recently discovered non-destructive editing in Photoshop.  I'm now carefully building my images so that each layer or adjustment layer can be independently edited without destroying the original content.  There's just one annoyance, I like to work on the highest resolution 16:9 ration I can but I need to export as a 1080p image.  Can I do that without flattening the image and resizing it?  This gets rid of all my careful non-destructive work and I can only work around it by saving a copy of my PSD, which is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the image: File->Export->Export As...

or: "Save for Web" Alt+Shift+Ctrl+S

There you can set the image size and fileformat. Is that what you ask for?

Comment: Hmm, CS6 doesn't seem to have that option.  I just have File->Export->Export As (Path to Video/Zoomify/Illustrator)

Comment: Ah, in that case you can use "Save for Web" Alt+Shift+Ctrl+S

Answer (score 1):

JPEGs can't have layers. The format doesn't support layers. There's no need to flatten the image before exporting as a JPEG. If you want to keep your layers, you will need to save the PSD. The PSD is your original artwork. Open the PSD when you need to output in different formats and sizes.

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't asking if I could have a jpeg with layers.  I was asking if I could easily explort resize+flatten+export without having to temporarily destructively change my image first.  I basically want to keep all my layers intact at 3840 x 2160 while exporting a jpeg at 1080p.

Comment: @Benj Yes. If you use "Export As", or "Save for web", but not "Save as". You should really edit you question to make it clearer. As it stands, sounds like you think JPEGs can have layers. Also note that before doing anything destructive you should always ensure you have saved the PSD. This is just common sense.

Comment: @Benj - another method is to duplicate the image using *Image > Duplicate*, before doing anything destructive. It will open a copy of the document, leaving the original still open.